# rails form builder quick question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formbuilder

I need to create a select statment with name and id like this but no using a form builder for one of the fields.

```
<select name="link_list[links][][link_to_path]" id="link_list_links__link_to_path">
```

All other fields are created like this

```
f.collection_select "link_to_path", LinkList.all, :url, :name
```

but i need to do it creating the id and name manually like this :

```
collection_select "link_list[links][]", "link_to_path",LinkList.all, :url, :name
```

this doesnt work at the moment.

Anyone have an answer for this  ?

thanks alot
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `options_for_select`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-

```
options_for_select(container, selected = nil)
```

For example:

```
options_for_select([["Dollar", "$"], ["Kroner", "DKK"]])
```

That generates the following html:

```
 <option value="$">Dollar</option>\n<option value="DKK">Kroner</option>
```

So in your case you need an array of links with their name and url like:

```
links = [['Google', 'www.google.com'], 'Yahoo', 'www.yahoo.com']
```

Then you can use `select_tag`

```
<%= select_tag :link, options_for_select(links)%>
```

Then if you want to have a default link you just inject the array like this:

```
links.insert(0, ["Default", "www.twitter.com"])
```